# Scene Builder Exception in Application (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, fxml, scenebuilder

I have installed Scene Builder and opened a new FXML Project just to test it out. I have seen on other computers that when a new FMXL Project is opened, the default code generates a button that displays text when clicked. However, when I try to run the main method of the default FXML Project, I get a stack error with a NullPointerException. I have searched many question threads on how to fix it but none of them really give me a concrete answer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
## JavaFXApplication2.java ##

package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Hafiz
 */
public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

## FXMLDocumentController.java ##

}
package javafxapplication2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author Hafiz
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}

## FXMLDocument.fxml ##

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
    <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
    <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
</children>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is caused by private method "handleButtonAction". Turn it to public and try then. Greetings